# Active directory Trusted domain user unable to login in to Linux (SLES ) using SSSD conf

Tags: active-directory

We have got two domain (Forest) with trusted connectivity ( default domain: example.com and trusted domain: test.com) users unable to login into Linux (SLES) user by using SSSD. Here is the configuration file sssd.conf created

```
    [sssd] 
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam
domains = example.com, test.com
debug_level = 9
[nss]
[pam]
[domain/example.com]
ad_domain = example.com
krb5_realm = EXAMPLE.COM
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = False
use_fully_qualified_names = False
fallback_homedir = /home/%u
access_provider = ad
simple_allow_groups = hecad
auto_private_groups = false
ldap_user_gecos = mail
debug_level = 9
[domain/test.com]
ad_domain = test.com
krb5_realm = TEST.COM
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = False
use_fully_qualified_names = False
fallback_homedir = /home/%u
access_provider = ad
simple_allow_groups = trust_group
auto_private_groups = false
ldap_user_gecos = mail
debug_level = 9
```

Please let me know,any solution for the trusted domain users login in the Linux (SLES)

Comment: Stack Overflow is just for programming questions. You may have better success asking at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com), which is for server-administration questions.

Answer (score 0):

•   Some parameters are missing in your sssd.conf according to the ideal example given on the SLES official documentation. They are as follows: -

a)  You have mentioned ‘id_provider = ad’ in your sssd.conf but it should be ‘id_provider = ldap’. Also, ‘ldap_id_mapping’ parameter has been set as ‘false’ whereas it should have been set as ‘true’ and map the ‘ldap_uri’ to the identity provider AD server, i.e., ‘ldap_uri = ldap://winsrv.ad.domain.com’

b)  Also, many required parameters like ‘auth_provider’, ‘ldap_search_base’ and ‘ldap_user_home_directory’ are missing from the configuration file.

I would suggest you to please check the below documentation link and then change the parameters in your SSSD.conf file accordingly.

https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000019065

Also, please refer the below Linux community thread discussion for more insights in this issue. It suggests the upgrading of the SAMBA Winbind package for retrieving users information from the trusted domain/forest.

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1540457

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. will check